# Use the "git diff" command to generate a patch file. After applying the patch file using the "patch" command, the permissions was lost

Tags: linux, git, patch

Use the "git diff" command to generate a patch file. After applying the patch file with the "patch" command, the permissions of the new file are lost; the file permissions are revised, and the application is normal after the patch is generated;

Comment: The Linux `patch` command is not a Git command and does not do *anything* with permissions—you get whatever permissions the OS delivers.

Comment: "new files" here means "files that did not exist before the patch", correct ?

Comment: yes. it was a new file

Comment: Any suggestions, I cannot use the git format-patch & git am command

Comment: If you cannot use `git am`, perhaps you cannot solve your problem, because you probably cannot use `git apply` either.

Answer (score 1):

Patches created using `git diff` can be re-applied using `git apply`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my solution was: traverse the patch file, find the new file name and permissions of the new file, and traverse to complete the modification.